# Does deleting a folder from disk also remove the pics from Picasa Webalbums if the folder is synced?

Tags: picasa-web-albums

I have a folder that I am deleting now to recover some space. The folder is **synced** to a [Picasa Webalbums](http://picasaweb.google.com) and the icon looks something like this (with a lot more pics):

[image]

- Does **synced** mean that next time I run Picasa after deleting the folder, the pics would be deleted from the online storage too?
- How can I keep the pics online but delete them from my disc?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While the help doesn't explicitly mention this case, the ['Sync to Web' basics](http://picasa.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?answer=106176) page has the following:

> Once you've enabled the Sync to Web feature, you can sync the following changes from Picasa to Picasa Web Albums:
>
> - Added or deleted photos

So I would assume that if you delete a folder locally it would also get deleted on the web.

My approach would be to:

a) back up the photos to DVD (just in case)
b) flip the "Sync to Web" switch
c) delete the local copy.

Comment: I also think this is something you'd need to handle if you eject a removable drive. So, I'm using a strategy like this for my removable drive (unsyncing before ejecting).